# How to determine the datatype of a PDTextbox value using PDFBox API

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Using PDFBox API, I want to add a restriction on PDTextbox field where if the generated PDF textbox is expecting a String value, it should not allow a Number value. Similarly, if the text box is expecting a Float value, it should not allow a String value.

I tried to determine the datatype by getting the COSBase object from PDField and analyzed the COSBase object but it seems the PDTextbox object which accepts String is neither of type COSString, nor COSFloat or COSInteger.

Below is the code snippet which always prints "######### Instance neither of COSInteger type, nor COSFloat, nor COSString" no matter what PDField it is.

```
if(field instanceof PDTextbox) {
PDTextbox textBox = (PDTextbox) field;
COSBase cosBaseObject = textBox.getCOSObject();

if(cosBaseObject instanceof COSInteger) {
    System.out.println("######### PDField instanceof COSInteger");
} else if(cosBaseObject instanceof COSFloat) {
    System.out.println("######### PDField instanceof COSFloat");
} else if(cosBaseObject instanceof COSString) {
    System.out.println("######### PDField instanceof COSString");
} else if(cosBaseObject instanceof COSNumber) {
    System.out.println("######### PDField instanceof COSNumber");
} else {
    System.out.println("######### Instance neither of COSInteger type, nor COSFloat, nor COSString");
}
}
```

If anyone has some pointers how to achieve it please let me know. Let me know if you need any further information. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I assume you are talking about regular AcroForm fields, not XFA form fields. Form field as such do not have a content type, done type may merely be enforced by JavaScript. Thus, the PDFBox objects representing the PDF objects don't reflect any data type.

Comment: Thanks mkl for your prompt response. Yes, I am talking about regular AcroForm fields and not XFA fields. So how do we enforce and restrict PDTextbox values to  a particular data type? Is it possible in PDFBox API? Without it, for my PDField where I am expecting phone numbers (Number), user can enter alphanumeric chars (String). Thanks!

Comment: PDFBox API allows you to read the JavaScript which controls the allowed field input but you have to interpret that JavaScript and restrict the data you put into a field accordingly.